# Reading QR codes with getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, qr-code

I am trying to make a mobile web app with a qr scanner. I know that it is possible to access a devices camera with [getUserMedia()](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/), I am going to prematurely assume that this will work on a mobile device. Provided this is true, what is required to turn this into a QR code reader?

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/zxing/zxing Look into the zebra crossing library. You can find it here. Best way to scan qr codes I have found.